# Android API version 27 still using SQLite 3.8. How to update to SQLite Database 3.19?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio

I have one old project which was bought along with Access Management SDK and device. I need to capture users data and send to firebase.

So what i did was to firstly upgrade the sdk version because is too old (22) and firebase could not work with it until i update.

In short, The sqlite code was working fine before and after the update, the local database has been crashing the app saying:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
ComponentInfo{com.fgtit.access/com.fgtit.access.MainActivity}: 
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not 
open database
```

Below is what is creating the database and manipulating it.

```
    public static boolean IsFileExists(String filename){
        File f=new File(filename);
        if(f.exists()){
            Log.d("UserDB", f.getName());
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    public void LoadAll(Context ctx){
        usersList.clear();
        String optionalPath ="/OnePass/users.db";
        String rootPath = ctx.getExternalFilesDir(optionalPath).getAbsolutePath();
        if(IsFileExists(rootPath )){
            db=SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(rootPath,null);
        }else{
            db=SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(rootPath,null);
            String sql="CREATE TABLE TB_USERS(userid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC,"
                    + "usertype INTEGER,"
                    + "groupid INTEGER,"
                    + "username CHAR(24),"
                    + "expdate BLOB,"
                    + "enlcon1 BLOB,"
                    + "enlcon2 BLOB,"
                    + "enlcon3 BLOB,"
                    + "fp1 BLOB,"
                    + "fp2 BLOB,"
                    + "fp3 BLOB,"
                    + "enllNO BLOB);";
            
            db.execSQL(sql);
        }

Below is my gradle configuration

    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.fgtit.access"
        versionCode 9
        versionName "2.7"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 30
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "mips"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation files('libs/android-core-3.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar')
    implementation files('libs/core-3.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar')
}
```

Has anything change since sdk 22 and what could be wrong here?

Comment: What version of Android was it tried on before and what version are you trying it on now?

Comment: @Andrew Android version 6.0. before and after. There is a specific device that needs it. All i want to do is to modify so it can work with our model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to API version 30 solved the problem.